# Monthly Sales- Totals command will only display 1 month instead of all 12

Tags: python

I am working on a monthly sales project for class and i cannot get the last thing to work. The totals command needs to add the monthly totals together and then average them out. I am only getting the output of the 12th month in the text file. I know there is something very minute i am missing but i cannot put my finger on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
# a file in the current directory
FILENAME = open("monthly_sales.txt")
sales_dict = {}

def display_menu():
    print("Monthly Sales program")
    print()
    print("COMMAND MENU")
    print("view   - View sales for specified month")
    print("edit   - Edit sales for specified month")
    print("totals - View sales summary for year")
    print("exit   - Exit program")

def main():
    display_menu() 


    for line in FILENAME.readlines():                  
            data = line.strip().split()                     
            month = data[0].strip()                         
            sale = float(data[1].strip())                   
            sales_dict[month] = sale                        

    FILENAME.close()                        



    while True:
        print()
        command = input("Command: ")
        command = command.lower()

        if command == 'view':
            month = input('Three-letter Month: ')  
            found = False                          
            for key in sales_dict.keys():             
                if month.lower() == key.lower():                    
                    print('Sales amount for', key, 'is {:,.2f}'.format(sales_dict[key]))
                    found = True                   
                    break
            if not found:                           
                print('Invalid three-letter Month')

        elif command == 'edit':                     
            month = input('Three-letter Month: ')
            found = False
            for key in sales_dict.keys():
                if month.lower() == key.lower():                    
                    sales_amount = float(input('Sales Amount: '))
                    sales_dict[key] = sales_amount  
                    print('Sales amount for', key, 'is {:,.2f}'.format(sales_dict[key]))
                    found = True
                    break
            if not found:                
                print('Invalid three-letter Month')

        elif command == 'totals':            
            total_sales = 0
            for key in sales_dict.keys():           
                total_sales = sales_dict[key]      
            monthly_average = total_sales / 12     
            print('Yearly total:     {:12,.2f}'.format(total_sales))
            print('Monthly Average:     {:9,.2f}'.format(monthly_average))

        elif command == "exit":
            print("Bye!")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid three-letter month")            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the hybrid addition-assignment operator (`+=`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`).

```py
for key in sales_dict.keys():           
    total_sales += sales_dict[key]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been staring at this screen for what feels like all of this lock down we are under. I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: @Arroyo123 , no problem! If this is the solution that works with you, then please mark it as "Accepted" :)